# Installed JRE8, JDK 13, ran all the suggestions on the other post of how to install rJava still not working

Tags: java, r, bash

macOS version is 10.14.5

r version 3.6.1

I tried to include rjava, however it always show me the error message:

*Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object 
'/Users/myname/Library/R/3.6/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Users/myname/Library/R/3.6/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-11.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/server/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/myname/Library/R/3.6/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found*

I did some researches and it guided me to:
https://zhiyzuo.github.io/installation-rJava/ 
and another thread here. I followed the instructions but nothing seem to work. I think one possible reason may be the java version of my computer. I installed both JDK 13 and JRE1.8.0_231-b11.

However when running *java -version*, it shows me this:

*java version "13" 2019-09-17*

*Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 13+33)*

*Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 13+33, mixed mode, sharing)*

and running  *ls -l /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/*, it shows me this:

*drwxr-xr-x  3 root  wheel  96 Oct 11 11:14 jdk-13.jdk*

And I compared my results with my coworker who has the same computer and more competent IT who finished all the config and installations for her. 
She ran *java -version* and her results like the following:

*openjdk version "1.8.0_212"*

*OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_212-b04)*

*OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.212-b04, mixed mode).*

Let me know what I can do! Thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: The JDK has a Java runtime environment bundled with it, so that's probably why you are seeing version '13' instead of '8'. If you want to change this you must put the JRE8 into the path environment variable ahead of the JDK13

Comment: @Jannik Hi! Thank you for your response. But I can't find the path for my JRE8 under library.

Comment: Afaik there can only be one jre installed in macOS. Maybe the jdk installation removed the JRE. You can try to install the java8 jdk because multiple jdks are supported.